# c++ why this static_assert works:

Tags: c++, c++17, constexpr, variant, static-assert

I have the following questions regarding the `constexpr`, I kinda understand that one cannot declare a `std::shared_ptr<T>` to be `const`, but why does the first `static_assert()` works?

Also, how does the second `static_assert()` work? I wanted to have an array of `std::variants`, which are consts, and wanted to have compile-time type-checking to enforce the type; however, it seems that if a `std::shared_ptr` is one of the variant type, then it cannot be declared `constexpr`; but if I declare the container as `std::tuple`, even without the `constexpr` annotation, (I) seemed to work;

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<int> intp;

const auto defaults = std::make_tuple(std::make_pair(1, true),
                                  std::make_pair(2, 3),
                                  std::make_pair(3, intp(nullptr)));


typedef std::variant<int, bool> MyVar;
constexpr MyVar var1 = 3;

// constexpr intp x = nullptr; (I)
//typedef std::variant<int, bool, intp> MyVar2; This doesn't work
//constexpr MyVar2 var2 = 3;

int main()
{
    // Q1): Why the following works, but (I) does not.
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(std::get<2>(defaults).second), intp>::value);
    // Q2): Why this works: is there a better way to say something like
    //      static_assert(actual_type(var1) == int);
    static_assert(std::get<int>(var1) == 3);
    //static_assert(x == nullptr);  This does not work 
}
```

Comment: Have any of the answers so far helped?

Answer (score 3):

> I kinda understand that one cannot declare a shared_ptr to be const, but why does the first static_assert works?

Because

```
static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(std::get<2>(defaults).second), intp>::value);
```

doesn't create a compile-time `stared_ptr`; only check if the type of `std::get<2>(defaults).second` is a `intp`.

This information is known compile time also if the values are available only run time.

> Also, how does the second static_assert work? I wanted to have an array of std::variants, which are consts, and wanted to have compile-time type-checking to enforce the type; however, it seems that if a shared_ptr is one of the variant type, then it cannot be declared constexpr; but if I declare the container as std::tuple, even without the constexpr annotation, (I) seemed to work;

Not sure what you mean.

If for "second static_assert work" do you mean

```
static_assert(std::get<int>(var1) == 3);
```

it's because `var1` is `constexpr` and `std::get()` (for `std::variant`) is `constexpr`; so `std::get<int>(var1)` it's a value that can be used, compile time, in a `static_assert()`
With

Answer (score 0):

> // Q1): Why the following works, but (I) does not. 
>       `static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(std::get<2>(defaults).second), intp>::value);`

Here's the magic: in C++ some expressions are considered ***unevaluated***. `decltype(...)` is one of them (refer to [dcl.type.simple])

What does it mean for `decltype(...)` to be unevaluated?

> In this context, the common purpose of
>   writing the expression is merely to refer to its type.

Think of it more like a fancy `typedef`. Nothing can ever actually be created from within this context. You can do some interesting things with it, like use incomplete types.

---

The reason why

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<int> intp;
constexpr intp x = nullptr;
```

doesn't work should now become obvious: this expression **is** evaluated, and since we know that we cannot create a `constexpr shared_ptr`, compilation fails.

---

> // Q2): Why this works: is there a better way to say something like 
>       `//      static_assert(actual_type(var1) == int);`? 
>       `static_assert(std::get<int>(var1) == 3);`

This works because a [`std::variant`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/variant) has a `constexpr` constructor, and you are constructing it with a compile-time integer value of `3` which constructs the `int` field of the variant.

Next, [`std::get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/get) on a `variant` is **also** marked `constexpr`, and since the variant is constructedd as `constexpr`, we can obtain the value `3` at compile-time.